# Setting key persistant to a modifier with xmodmap , not loading unless I source .xinitrc

Tags: linux, bash, debian, xmodmap

So I'm just trying to assign Control_R , to a different function such as `mod3` with `xmodmap` , for that I have added the following line on `.xinitrc`

```
[[ -f ~/.Xmodmap ]] && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Beforehand I have done

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

And appended the lines I needed to add my functonality

```
clear control
add control = Control_L
add mod3 = Control_R
```

Anytime I `startx` if I `xmodmap` the output hasn't changed , but as soon as I do `source .xinitrc` it does the change I desired:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Control_R (0x69)    ------------------------> 
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

How can you achieve this functionality in `Debian Buster` ?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't actually using `startx` but merely meant start X. I suppose you are using a display manager?

Comment: Or maybe you *appended* the line to .xinitrc...paste the full file?

Comment: Shall I paste it in the thread (its quite long) , or can I just put a link to termbin ?

Comment: Either is fine (to me).

Comment: ~/.Xmodmap https://termbin.com/4x3fl
~/.xinitrc https://termbin.com/41wb

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the ~/.xinitrc , as you can see the first 3 lines are commented out , were supposed to be another way to make this functionality persistent without having to load other file like ~/.Xmodmap , but also malfunctions

Comment: So are you really using `startx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, at least under my circumstances (using `Debian Buster`) to make this work you need to enter some kind of delay of execution of the command.
Thus the command will end up like this `vi ~/.xinitrc`

```
[ -f ~/.Xmodmap ] && { sleep; xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap; } &
```

Which contradicts the actual Archwiki page to set this feature up (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap ) . I don't know if ArchLinux has its own particularities , but should someone had found the same error check if the line above will solve it.

Comment: What do you see in `~/somefile` if you do `[ -f ~/.Xmodmap ] && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap &> ~/somefile`?

Comment: If I write that line in .xinitrc , `~/somefile` is created , empty . If I invoke it in the terminal the same file is created , again empty

Comment: Sounds like something is resetting the result as there's no error output. Does `[ -f ~/.Xmodmap ] && { sleep; xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap; }` (without the `&` at the end) work? (Btw, are you really using just `sleep`, instead of e.g. `sleep 1`?

Comment: It does work without the `&` at the end . And I'm just using as I showed you `sleep`

Comment: For the record, sleep doesn't actually work without a time length parameter, so sounds like it's a very delicate race condition between `xmodmap` and something triggered outside `.xinitrc` that reset its effect. I wonder if it's a keymap setting or so. See what's in `~/somefile` with `[ -f ~/.Xmodmap ] && { setxkbmap -query &>> ~/somefile; xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap; setxkbmap -query &>> ~/somefile }` in `.xinitrc`. (Unless we are lucky enough the output from the two instances might be identical; but at least it will show whether you are using a non-default keymap. `xmodmap` will likely work btw.)